# filtrar en una tabla a partir de dos input

Tags: javascript, php, html

Tengo una tabla con valores, pero quiero filtrar a partir de los resultados de dos input.

ejemplo:
input1: name="latitud"
input2: name="longitud"

en el resultado de la tabla quiero que se filtre las dos columna "latitud" y "longitud" cumpliendo las dos condiciones de los dos input.

De antemano muchas gracias.

```
<!--        Aqui va la tabla-->
     <div class="container">
      <div class="card bg-light" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 70px;">
          <div class="card-header">
              <h5 class="card-title">Registros ANA</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" >
         <thead class="thead-dark">
             <tr style=" text-align: center;">
             <th scope="col">Latitud</th>
             <th scope="col">Longitud</th>
             <th scope="col">Referencia</th>
             <th scope="col">Fecha</th>
           </tr>
         </thead>
            <tbody id="tblCoordenadas">
               <?php
                    if (!is_null($Registros)) {
                        foreach ($Registros as $_reg) {
                            echo "<tr style='text-align: center;'>";
                            echo "<td>" . $_reg[1] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $_reg[2] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $_reg[3] . "</td>";
                            echo "<td>" . $_reg[4] . "</td>";
                            echo "</tr>";
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo '<tr><td style="text-align: center;" colspan="8">-- No existen datos de solicitudes --</td></tr>';
                    }
                 ?>       
         </tbody>
       </table>
 </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Fin de la tabla-->
```

Comment: Puedes comenzar [leyendo este artículo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [este otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola buenos días @CristianCamilo lo que quiero es hacer un filtro en una tabla pero que cumpla el resultado de dos input es decir si tengo esto, un input llamado "latitud" y este tiene como value= 123 y el otro input llamado "longitud" y este tiene como value = 85, en la tabla tengo las columnas id, nombre, latitud y longitud, entonces quiero que la condición de búsqueda en la tabla cumpla con con los valores de los inputs 123  y 85 de las columnas latitud y longitud de la tabla.. espero y me comprendan.  Saludos.